# PC won't post, black screen

Tags: windows-7, motherboard, bios, post, cmos

I was formatting some old harddrives and toying with my desktop recently and now it wont post. When I turn it on the LEDs turn on, the DVD drive has power. The harddrives seem to have power to them as do the fans.

One time during troubleshooting I got it to post,kind of, it displayed the following: Award BootBlock BIOS v1.0 BIOS ROM Checksum error

I popped out the motherboard battery to attempt to fix this issue (reset the bios settings). I have also done the following to attempt to fix it:

- removed all hardrives to only the
  boot disk
- reduced RAM to one stick
- removed video card and tried onboard
  video
- attempted to boot with various live
  disks / recovery disks

What should be the next move?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to tell apart a CPU defect from a mainboard defect?](https://superuser.com/questions/228946/any-way-to-tell-apart-a-cpu-defect-from-a-mainboard-defect)

Answer (score 1):

Reset your BIOS the safe way using the jumpers, here's your manual:

http://www.jetway.com.tw/jw/download_address.asp?downid=7663&proname=PA78VM3-H&downtype=Manual-English&isbios=

Comment: I moved the jumpers to the 2nd and 3rd spot, waited and then moved it back.  When I booted it still didn't post but at least my keyboard lit up.

Comment: I will try more alternatives tomorrow, I have it running on onboard video right because I took out my video card.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Sorry,that's as far as I would go before changing the mobo

Answer (score 0):

See if there is a jumper on the board that resets the bios. But if it won't boot from the hard drive or live cd then...

Sounds to me like you've done what could be done. Time for a new motherboard. You could take the board to a good electronics/computer repair shop and have them test it. A new board might cost you the same as having it tested.

Sorry, I know that's not really an answer, but this has happened to me before and a new board was the fix.

Comment: Unfortunately I have had to replace a motherboard before as well and all signs were pointing that way.

Comment: I am going to try to replace the battery.  I read about a jumper on the motherboard before but I am not sure how to go about it. I have a JetWay JPA78VM3 if that helps at all.

Comment: I read one way of resetting the bios is after taking the battery out, put a coin over the contacts, that shorts it, should I suppose reset then. Though i'd perhaps expect cmos/bios to reset by just taking out the battery not sure how quick.

Comment: I would not recommend using a coin. You may still be able to save it. See Tog's comment. There is a jumper just left of the sata connectors. Just move the jumper over one pin, boot it, see if anything happens. You may get a message, "CMOS reset". Then power down, switch it back, and you may be good to go.