# How do I install the Windows 7 boot loader?

Tags: windows-7, bootloader

I have 2 hard disks, on first I have installed win xp. I boot into xp and run setup of win7 and installed it on second hard disk. Now the problem is that win7 bootloader is installed on first harddisk, so if I remove the first harddisk, I cannot boot into win7.

How I can move / install bootloader of win7 on second hard disk?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's try automatic installation and if that doesn't work there is also a manual installation method;
 you may have problems with drive letter allocations after this, but that's not too bad to deal with.

1. Boot from the **Windows 7 Installation Medium**.

   [image]
2. Click on **Repair your computer** or press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

   [image]
3. Click on **Startup Repair** or press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, let it repair and **restart your computer**.
4. Don't forget to **remove the installation medium**.

If this doesn't work, try a manual installation (replace `C:` by your drive, `X:` by the medium):

1. Boot from the **Windows 7 Installation Medium**.
2. Click on **Repair your computer** or press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.
3. Click on **Command Prompt** or press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.
4. Let's fix the Main Boot Record and place the Boot Sector back, **enter this**:

   ```
   bootrec.exe /fixmbr
   X:\boot\bootsect.exe /nt60 all /force
   ```
5. Then ask it (nicely!) to try and rebuild your BCD data from scratch, **enter this**:

   ```
   xcopy C:\boot\bcd C:\windows\justInCase /v /e /h /k /r /o /x /y
   del C:\boot\bcd
   bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd
   ```
6. If you're lucky, this'll work and **you'll see a message** telling you everything went OK.
7. Reboot your PC by **closing all the dialogs**, or **enter this**:

   ```
   shutdown -r -t 0
   ```
8. Don't forget to **remove the installation medium**.
9. **If you need to recover** the BCD due to failure, repeat steps 1 - 3 and **enter this:**

   ```
   xcopy C:\windows\justInCase C:\boot\bcd /v /e /h /k /r /o /x /y
   ```

Comment: Hey, that's not how my answer looked! :-) Many thanks @TomWij for taking the effort to make it pretty. I appreciate it.

Comment: Wanted to improve the formatting a bit, but then I had the urge to add in more information. I'm glad you appreciate it...