# Dell Desktop Inspiron 3647 do not turn on at all (no fun, leds, nothing) but all peripherals pass through PSU BIST test

Tags: hardware-failure, dell-inspiron

I am trying to fix a Dell desktop Inspiron 3647 that is not turning on at all. I've searched a lot about this, but I only find the same suggestions that don't help me with my problem.

When I press the power button nothing happens. **No fan, no beep, not even the LED lights**.

1. The first test I ran was the power button. But it passed the Continuity Test. I even replaced with another power button.
2. Then I ran the [PSU BIST](https://www.dell.com/support/article/br/pt/brdhs1/sln308658/power-supply-unit-psu-built-in-self-test-bist-desktop?lang=en) which led me to the conclusion that HD, Motherboard (at least in this test), CD Drive, and the PSU itself seems to be working fine.
3. Then I changed the CMOS battery for a new one, but yet nothing happens.
4. I removed the RAM and the CD Drive, and still, the computer doesn't turn on.
5. I also tested with a known-good PSU as suggested by @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007

What else could I do to find what is preventing the computer to turn on?

#### EDIT:

I believe the problem is the motherboard or CPU, since I removed/replaced almost everything (including PSU and power button) and still, the computer gives no sign of life. However, as I said, the **motherboard also passed the PSU BIST** test. So, should not this indicate that the motherboard is working well?

Comment: In general, if you remove all the RAM, then the motherboard should beep like there's no RAM.  If it's not, then the motherboard is probably faulty.  Try a different, known-good PSU, and if that doesn't help, try a new motherboard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to tell apart a CPU defect from a mainboard defect?](https://superuser.com/questions/228946/any-way-to-tell-apart-a-cpu-defect-from-a-mainboard-defect)

Comment: Thanks for your help. But the motherboard is passing the PSU BIST test. Shouldn't this indicate that the motherboard is working?

Comment: My understanding is that the PSU BIST only really tests the PSU.  I don't think passing that test rules out a motherboard issue.