# Dell Inspiron 15R 5521 - No Display No Keyboard Motherboard beeps on RAM removal *

Tags: laptop, keyboard, motherboard, dell-inspiron, laptop-repair

I have Inspiron 15R 5521. It is not giving display. Keyboard is also not working. I removed RAM and CMOS battery one by one and motherboard gave correct number of beeps each time.

I shut-downed the Windows 8 after using it for around continuous 8 hours as per my routine usage. When i tried to turn it on next day, I got the above problem.

It's caps lock light (only light on kb) is not turning on. FN + d keys are also not working. I tried an external PS2 keyboard through USB-2-PS2 adapter but it did not work - all 3 lights blinked on power on but after that keyboard did not work.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn-on is the favorite time for weak hardware components to fail, when power goes
brutally from zero to full.

It is impossible for us to diagnose the problem in remote control; this can only
be done from your end. All we can do is guess (I would vote for the motherboard).

You may decide to fix the problem the only way you can, by swapping components
such as power-supply and whatever else you have available.

Buying new components just for testing can quickly become very expensive.
If the computer is not new, it might be better to invest in a new computer.

A repair-shop will have the tools to analyze and the components to swap for
analyzing the problem. It might be the more economical alternative.

Comment: Thanks for reply. If motherboard beeps, does it mean that both motherboard and processor are okay and getting power?

Comment: If the fans are starting when power is turned on, then *probably* the power-supply unit is OK. But a conclusive analysis requires tools. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/228953/8672) for the complete analysis process.