# How to diagnose/distinguish motherboard/CPU issues?

Tags: memory, ssd, cpu, motherboard, bsod

For the last few months my PC is acting weird. Random App crashes, Chrome tab crashes, memory errors, apps simply disappearing, BSOD with errors not helping at all, random restarts (Event-log shows unknow error only). First, it usually happened around 70-80% RAM usage (32GB). After a while it started to happen even after a fresh restart.

Temperatures are completely fine, except for one. In HWInfo64 for one sensor it was showing 94-105C and the name was TEMPL4. I couldn't find anything what that might be, the only clue I found is that "unused" sensors can report such temps from the motherboard. By touch I couldn't find any area in the case with such temps. - The VRM on the board is watercooled.

My first attempt was testing my memory with both Memtest64 and Memtest86. Didn't show any errors, but sometimes I could reproduce apps freezing during running Memtest64. After a while I decided to switch the memory to new modules. Same brand, same type, same size. Unfortunatelly, it didn't help.

For the last 6 years I was running 3 Samsung 950 PROs in RAID0. My next idea was that the drives had some kind of issue. I switched to the 3 SSDs to a single 980 PRO, and did a fresh install of Win11. Didn't help, issues are still showing up.

My next guess is that it's either a motherboard issues (north bridge maybe) or CPU.

Any ideas where I should continue debugging? I don't have any spare boards or CPUs to test.

Comment: Unfortunately, you seem to have done all the testing you can without having spare parts.  At this point, you need to make a decision, what is your time and effort worth?  You have already bought new RAM and replaced the drives.  A CPU is easier to replace than the motherboard, but the motherboard is more likely the culprit, as it has more parts to fail...  Thats your decision to make.  The only *good* thing is that once you find the problem, you basically are just a few parts from a 2nd PC.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any way to tell apart a CPU defect from a mainboard defect?](https://superuser.com/questions/228946/any-way-to-tell-apart-a-cpu-defect-from-a-mainboard-defect)

Comment: To isolate whether the issue is hardware or software (well, OS), switch to running from a USB drive for a while, long enough to see if you get BSOD. Since you use HWINFO, I assume you're using Windows, so you might need to try an alternative, such as Ubuntu on a live SUB flash drive.No need to install the OS, just use the included applications, and install Chrome (to memory; it will not be retained), which caused errors in Windows.