# Optiplex 990 powering on and off

Tags: dell-optiplex

As soon as i power on the PSU the pc starts itself without even pressing the power button then shuts down
So the fans and everything thing powers on for 1 second then powers off repeatedly till i power off the psu
I switched rams cleaned the whole pc removed the batteries nothing works
Even when i disconnect everything only the MB is attached to the psu (no ram) it does the same loop
Any thoughts?

Comment: Put the memory back in and start in BIOS.  Does it start that way?

Comment: I cant enter to bios
It doesnt even turn on for 1 second

Comment: Take it to a local repair shop and see if it can be economically repaired. It may be time for a new computer.

Comment: So theres nothing i can do ? Itsnt my main pc but im remote rn and theres none around

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any way to tell apart a CPU defect from a mainboard defect?](https://superuser.com/questions/228946/any-way-to-tell-apart-a-cpu-defect-from-a-mainboard-defect)

Comment: Enter the service tag on dell.com website .

Comment: If you unplug it from the motherboard it still does the weird loop cycle?  If it does work in isolation then maybe the power button is broken?

Answer (score 1):

> As soon as i power on the PSU the pc starts itself without even
> pressing the power button then shuts down
>
> Comment:  Starting in BIOS did not start.

So at this point, the issue most likely is CPU and/or Motherboard.

Either way, and assuming the computer is past warranty period, the most likely path forward is to replace it. Putting a CPU and/or motherboard in an older PC is generally not economical.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Solution for me was to purchase a new power supply from seller on Amazon for $25.00 dollars. Original Dell factory OEM power supply. Problem solved. That may be the solution for you.